# Feeding a Sequence into Akka Stream's combine()

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

How do you use Akka Stream's [`combine`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source/combine.html) method to combine a sequence of Sources? For example, `val sources = Seq[Source[T,_]]`.

It seems there is no method signature which takes a Seq/Iterable/etc...
It instead requires the first and second elements to combine separately, and then varargs for the rest?

```
def combine[T, U](first: Source[T, _], second: Source[T, _], rest: Source[T, _]*)(strategy: Int => Graph[UniformFanInShape[T, U], NotUsed]): Source[U, NotUsed]
```

*What is a clearest way to call combine with a Seq?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this perhaps:

```
val source = sources match {
  case Seq(a, b, rest@_*) => combine(a, b, rest:_*)(strategy)
  case Seq(a) => a
  case _ => ??? // handle case when there are no sources: throw? empty source?
}
```

Comment: Amazing thank-you! I was going down an ugly path with iterators, but this is lovely. What is the name of the magic happening with `case Seq(a,b,rest@_*)`?